# node v8-profiler: is there a performance hit when not profiling?

Tags: node.js, profiling

I'd like to include the "v8-profiler" npm package in my production node.js application and provide a method to toggle CPU profiling with startProfiling/stopProfiling in case I need to gather performance data.

When I'm not actively profiling CPU usage with it, is there any performance impact to including the v8-profiler package in my application? Or is it essentially dormant in that case? I'm using node 4.4.x if that makes a difference.

From the code, it doesn't seem like there would be a problem with including it, but I might be missing something.

Thanks,

-- Steven